# Assert.Inconclusive() in NUnit on MonoDevelop

Tags: nunit, monodevelop

I'm just starting to use MonoDevelop on OsX and running NUnit tests. It all works great except for that all my Assert.Inconclusive() show up as errors instead of as (as in my NUnit test runner on my Windows machine) inconclusive. Despite all my Googling on the subject, I cannot find any mentions on what I should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

I was just doing it wrong. What I wanted was [Ignore], not Assert.Inconclusive().